# Python/matplot "fill_between" stops just above y=7.5 where I want it to stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to get the shaded colors to stop at the y=7.5 bar, but the green one doesn't go far enough (i.e. to the line). Is anyone able to figure this out? Many thanks!

```
# sensitivity analysis
sensitivity = pd.DataFrame()
for x in exit_probabilities:
    for y in exit_valuations:
        sensitivity.loc[y, x] = vc_valuation_method_mod(0.15, 5,x, y, 0.5, 5, 10, 6, 100, 80, 2.5)[0]
print(sensitivity)

#Plot data
sns.set(font_scale = 1.5, style = 'white', rc=None)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,10))

a = sensitivity.plot(y = 0.2, ax = ax, linestyle = '--', color = 'gray')

b = sensitivity.plot(y = 0.3, ax = ax, linestyle = '-.', color = 'gray')
c = sensitivity.plot(y = 0.4, ax = ax, linestyle = ':', color = 'gray')
d = ax.hlines(y=7.5, xmin=100, xmax=900, colors='black', linestyles='-', lw=2, label='Single Short Line')


#ax.fill_between(a, d, alpha=2) 
# fill between y=0.75 and df.y
# Adds headers
sensitivity.columns =['.1', '.15','.2','.25','.3','.35','.4'] 
ax.fill_between(x=sensitivity.index, y1=sensitivity['.2'], y2=7.5, where=sensitivity['.2'] > 7.5, interpolate=True)
ax.fill_between(x=sensitivity.index, y1=sensitivity['.3'], y2=np.maximum(sensitivity['.2'], 7.5), 
                where=sensitivity['.3'] > 7.5, interpolate=True)
ax.fill_between(x=sensitivity.index, y1=sensitivity['.4'], y2=np.maximum(sensitivity['.3'], 7.5), 
                where=sensitivity['.4'] > 7.5, interpolate=True)

plt.show()

sns.despine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first fill (the blue one) goes fine.

The second fill should go:

- the top is `sensitivity['.3']`
- the bottom is `sensitivity['.2']`, but only where it is larger than `7.5`, so, take the maximum of `sensitivity['.2']` and `7.5`
- the `where` parameter is a limit on the x-axis; the filling should start where `sensitivity['.3']` becomes larger than `7.5`; if you'd start earlier, matplotlib would fill between the horizontal at `7.5` and `sensitivity['.3']`

The third fill is similar to the second.  Together it would look like:

```py
ax.fill_between(x=sensitivity.index, y1=sensitivity['.2'], y2=7.5, where=sensitivity['.2'] > 7.5, interpolate=True)
ax.fill_between(x=sensitivity.index, y1=sensitivity['.3'], y2=np.maximum(sensitivity['.2'], 7.5), 
                where=sensitivity['.3'] > 7.5, interpolate=True)
ax.fill_between(x=sensitivity.index, y1=sensitivity['.4'], y2=np.maximum(sensitivity['.3'], 7.5), 
                where=sensitivity['.4'] > 7.5, interpolate=True)
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem of not having enough points in the x-axis (`sensitivity.index`).  `interpolate=True` doesn't always create a perfect interpolation. Would it be possible to have more values in your index?